# URLにスペースが含まれる場合のif ($_GET文の記述方法をお教えいただけませんでしょうか。

Tags: php

URLの中にスペースが含まれるような以下のケースの場合(Hamamatsu%20FC)、$_GET文をどの様に記述したらよいかお教え願いませんでしょうか。

以下のif ($_GET文では機能せず、試しに以下のif ($_GET['name'] == 'Hamamatsu FC')の' Hamamatsu FC 'を' Hamamatsu%20FC 'の様に変更し試しましたが駄目なようです。

http://xxxx/detail.php?product_id=2&name= Hamamatsu%20FC

if ($_GET['name'] == ' Hamamatsu FC ') {
  $arrval = Array(Hamamatsu FC);

Comment: スクリプトの"<?php"のすぐあとの行に`var_dump($_GET['name']);`という内容を追記して、実行してみてください。
`$_GET['name']`にどんな値（文字列）が入っているか確認できますから、比較文字列がどういけないのかわかると思います。それでもわからなければ表示された内容を追記してください。

Comment: multipost ( http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9956 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Stringの値の前後の空白(半角空白, %20, +) は $_GET では削除されます

```
# name=" Hamamatsu%20FC "
http://xxxx/detail.php?product_id=2&name= Hamamatsu%20FC
# name=" Hamamatsu%20FC%20"
http://xxxx/detail.php?product_id=2&name=%20Hamamatsu%20FC%20
# name="%20%20%20Hamamatsu%20FC%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"
http://xxxx/detail.php?product_id=2&name=%20%20%20Hamamatsu%20FC%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

上記すべて $_GET['name'] の値は以下となります。

```
name="Hamamatsu FC"
```

よって、条件は以下となります

```
if ($_GET['name'] == 'Hamamatsu FC') {
```

Comment: Yukihiro Honda様，ご教授頂きまして感謝いたします。URL中にHamamatsu%20FCと表示されることは問題ないのですね。いろいろと試した結果、その他は維持で次の様に変更することで解決致しました。$arrval = Array("Hamamatsu FC");